# Are powers of primes the sum of two primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was thinking about this and am wondering if it is true. Currently trying to look for a counter example, but haven't found anything yet.

Conjecture: $p^\alpha$ can be written as the sum of two primes, for any prime $p$, $\alpha \geq 2 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What about $121=11^2$?

Comment: Primes (except 2) are always odd.

Comment: Or even $3^3$...

Comment: Ah looked at small squares first didn't consider 27... Wonder when this does hold true?
i.e works for 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 5^2, etc.

Comment: Don't worry about it...

Comment: I will add my thoughts on the OP's comment at least.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p=3$ and $\alpha = 3$. Then $p^3=3^3=27.$ A contradiction would be,
$$27=2+25=3+24=5+22=7+20=11+16=13+14=17+10=19+8=23+4.$$
There are no other possibilities, and so this conjecture is false.

The case of showing when this is true reminds me of [Goldbach's Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture) which states that "Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes".

Here is my construction of the reason why there is no conjecture on the odds (or primes):

Let $p>2$ be a prime. Then $p$ is odd, hence $p^{\alpha}, \, \alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ is odd (product of odds is odd). Suppose there are two primes $a,b>2$ such that $a+b=p^{\alpha}$. Then one of $a,b$ is even while the other is odd (sum of evens is even, sum of odds is even). Hence one of $a,b$ is not prime. Therefore no power $\alpha$ of a prime $p>2$ can be expressed as the sum of two primes $a,b>2$.

I will include any proofs not provided on request.

Note that there are cases where a prime + 2 will produce a prime $p^1$

Comment: What about $5^2 = 23 + 2$?

Comment: Note my edit. There are many examples like that. I think this lends itself to your earlier comment though, 2 gets to a prime $p^1$ and maybe other powers often. Nice ;)

Comment: @DennisMeng read: unless one of a,b is 2

Comment: @DennisMeng Primes greater than 2 are odd. I think I have that condition in there. Keep going though, I want a clean post.

Comment: Bah, didn't see the $a, b > 2$ part. Ignore me.

Comment: Actually @DennisMeng that warranted a clarity repeat at the tail of the construction. Thanks. This thing is going to go community if I keep this up hehe.

Comment: Ah I missed that as well. How about when we allow $ 2 $? Then we have $2 + b = p^\alpha $. If we fix $ \alpha $, is there a way to generate solutions to this equation?

Comment: @user95072 Yeah that's what I was thinking. On the question of when it is true, this generates an excellent question. There are so many consecutive prime sequences of the form p, p+2, but what about $2+b=p^{\alpha}$ where $\alpha>1$? This is an interesting project. Just writing a program to find a set of them sounds worthwhile. I think I might do that tomorrow just to see what they look like. I can program this, but I have already done alot of work like this on primes before, and I know I will probably still arrive at a hit or miss situation (probability near unity :)).